# Can not google sign-in using Firebase. Error: Illegal url for new iframe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Can not google sign-in using Firebase.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal url for new iframe -
> https://%22tweets-5df.firebaseapp.com%22%2C/__/auth/iframe?apiKey...
> at _.yl (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:114:96)
> at bm (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:124:18)
> at _.cm (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:125:26)
> at _.jm (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:130:147)
> at _.An.openChild (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:207:378)
> at _.An.open (cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:212:12)
> at _openIframe (iframe.ts:82:1)
> at async BrowserPopupRedirectResolver.initAndGetManager (popup_redirect.ts:126:1)

.env

```
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID = "tweets-5df"
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN ="tweets-5df.firebaseapp.com"
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET = "tweets-5df.appspot.com"
```

firebase.ts

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

const {
  REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
  REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
} = process.env;

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
  appId: REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });

export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase;
```

`<GoogleButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}> Sign in with google </GoogleButton>`

When I click on GoogleButton in console show "Error: Illegal url for new iframe ". Does not go to authentication page.

Comment: In your .env file is  REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN starting with https?

Comment: No.  REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN ="tweets-5d02f.firebaseapp.com"